# How can I send a Postmanrequest to my AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, postman, microservices, azure-aks

I deployed my microservices with Azure Kubernetes. Now I want to address my API gateway via Postman. However, I get a timeout.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
apigateway-77875f89cb-pzc9z   1/1     Running   0          62m
contacts-5ccc69f74-j7s5b      1/1     Running   0          62m
templates-579fc4984b-scjs7    1/1     Running   0          62m
```

The pods are flawless and  the docker containers too.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apigateway-front
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apigateway-front
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apigateway-front
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
        - name: apigateway-front
          image: containerregistry.azurecr.io/apigateway:11
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 512Mi
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8800
            name: apigateway

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apigateway-front
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8800
  selector:
    app: apigateway-front


---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: contacts
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: contacts
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: contacts
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: contacts
        image: containerregistry.azurecr.io/contacts:12
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 512Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8100
          name: contacts

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: contacts
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8100
  selector:
    app: contacts
---


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: templates
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: templates
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: templates
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: templates
        image: containerregistry.azurecr.io/templates:13
        resources:
         requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
         limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 512Mi
        ports:
         - containerPort: 8200
           name: templates
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: templates
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8200
  selector:
    app: templates
```

I have described my API gateway microservice as LoadBalancer in the Yaml file. So I got an external IP address.

```
kubectl get service apigateway
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
apigateway   LoadBalancer   10.0.46.173   20.50.210.127   8800:31701/TCP   4h5m
```

So everything seems to be ok. But if I want to send a request in the Postman, I get a timeout.

20.50.210.127:8800/authenticate

```
POST http://20.50.210.127:8800/authenticate
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 20.50.210.127:8800
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.25.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 005b6876-5b7d-4688-b111-2d90fafb5051
Host: 20.50.210.127:8800
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: On your Deployment you set the label `app: apigateway` but the selector for the service to `selector: app: apigateway-front` - so maybe your service targets a non existent label/deployment?

Comment: I edited my Yaml file but I still get a timeout

Comment: There are several things you can check: can you "talk" to the service from within the Cluster? If possible you could `exec -ti -- bash` into one pod in the same namespace or run a "one shot" pod with curl and other tools. From inside this pod you could try to curl the service under "http://apigateway-front:8800" and see if you get an answer. Otherwise have you checked if any Azure Firewalls are in place?

Comment: You can try to use the `port-forward` to check if the pods work fine.

Comment: Do you have an ingress for that service?